# Angular JS service not found (Failed to instantiate module)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've 3 modules with the following hierarchy

- app.js

  - module.js

    - sub-module.js

**app.js**

```
(function(ng, module){
    module.config([function(){
        console.log('main app');    
    }]);

}) (angular, angular.module('app', ['module']));
```

**module.js**

```
(function(ng, module){

    module.config(['service', function(service){ 
        console.log('module');
    }]);

}) (angular, angular.module('module', ['sub-module']));
```

**sub-module.js**

```
(function (ng, module) {
    module.factory('service', [function () {
        console.log('test');
        return {};
    }]);

})(angular, angular.module('sub-module', []));
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="module.js"></script>
    <script src="sub-module.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8BHhpZHrIYpTd5gn0IsZ?p=preview

I've this error in console: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]**

What's wrong with the injector?

Comment: I am no expert but it looks like you define your modules wrong. What did you try to accomplish in your example?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to configure a provider called service which doesn't exist:

NOTE: Next time use the non-minified version of angular, it will give you more info.

If you would like to configure your factory called service, you must make it a provider:

```
(function (ng, module) {
    module.provider('service', [function () {
        console.log('test');
        return {
          $get: function() { return {}; };
        };
    }]);

})(angular, angular.module('sub-module', []));
```

Also you configure providers by injecting name_of_the_service + Provider, in your case:

```
(function(ng, module){

    module.config(['serviceProvider', function(serviceProvider){ 
        console.log('module');
    }]);

}) (angular, angular.module('module', ['sub-module']));
```

Comment: From docs: `Services are registered to modules via the Module API. Typically you use the Module#factory API to register a service:`. See example here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services Your answer may solve the issue, but still doesn't explain why my code is not working

Comment: You can't inject a service in a config block, you can only configure providers. Since you quote docs: `Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.`

Comment: Ok this makes much more sense now. Will try your approach and will let you know, thanks